# Smarty template not loading updated php values, keeps loading cached template

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I am using smarty 3.x I have the following template:

index.tpl

```
<html>
<body>Time: {$time}
</body>
</html>
```

and the file index.php

```
<?php

require 'Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->debugging = true;
$smarty->caching = true;
$smarty->setTemplateDir('/www/');
$smarty->setCompileDir('/compiled/');
$smarty->setCacheDir('/cache/');

$time= date("H:i:s");
$smarty->assign("time", $time);
$smarty->display("index.tpl");
?>
```

When I load the page the template is loaded displaying the time, upon refreshing the page the time is not updated (if i enable the debug in smarty the var $time is updated). Basically the page is loading from cache and not updating the time variable. I have looked through the documentation, but was not clear on what configuration I should be using to ensure these values are updated and the templates are optimally loaded (ie. performance).

Comment: I'd say that explicitly enabling caching will lead to the problems you experience. Have you tried not setting `$smarty->caching`? Have you read http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.tpl and http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.caching.tpl ?

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the direction of this page http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.cacheable.tpl#cacheability.variables

simply using this: $smarty->assign("time", $time, true); works the true at the end ensures this output is not cached